# Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator even though second route has context

Tags: flutter, navigation, widget, navigator

```
 //main.dart file
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:messenger/widgets/splash_screen.dart';

 void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
   }

 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {


 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  theme: ThemeData(
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        color: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0.0,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
        actionsIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black)),
    fontFamily: "Ubuntu",
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    primaryColor: Color(0xff0084FF),
  ),
  
  home: Column(
  
    children: <Widget>[
      SizedBox(height: 30.0,),
      ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () => navigation(context),
             child: Text("to splash screen"))
      ],
     ),
   );
  }

 navigation(BuildContext context) {
   Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>SplashScreen()));
 }
  }


   //SplashScreen.dart file


   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
  import 'package:messenger/widgets/login_button.dart';

   class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
 }

 class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   double imageSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3;
    return Scaffold(

      body: Center(
  
       child: Image.asset(
      "images/logo.png",
      width: imageSize,
      height: imageSize,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
      horizontal: 16.0,
      vertical: 16.0,
    ),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        LoginButton(text: "Continue with Facebook",onPressed: (){

        },
   colour: Color(0xff3b5998),
    leading: Image.asset("images/facebook-logo.png",
   ),
  ),
        
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
 }
  }
```

Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.
Maybe I didn't understand the concept of context well that's why I am getting the
error.Why is this error happening? The second widget that is SplashScreen has
context. But still I am getting the error. Is there any problem in the code that I
missed?

Answer (score 0):

bro you its not good way to call `Navigator.push` in Navigator please try to call in specific function or you can call this in `ink well` so please remove
the **Navigator(BuildContext context)**after thats its will work fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

**here is the code that can solve your navigation problem **

```
enter code here
  
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'screen/splashScreen.dart';

class DemoNavigation extends StatefulWidget {
  const DemoNavigation({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

   @override
    _DemoNavigationState createState() => _DemoNavigationState();
    }

  class _DemoNavigationState extends State<DemoNavigation> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
       child: Column(
          children: [
            Text("Navigator Demo"),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
            // here is the function that your are using
                  navigation(context);
              },
               child: Text("TO Next Screen"),
             ),
           ],
        ),
      ),
   );
}

    /// here you need to change the context that your are passing to build 
     /// copy this   
    void navigation(BuildContext context) {
       Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => 
      SplashScreen()));
   }
}
```